# Memory leak when using hdf in table format?

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

under pandas, each time i use the table format instead fixed format my memory consuption explode.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(seed=10)
df = pd.DataFrame ({'ID' : ['foo', 'bar'] * 10000000,
                'ORDER' : np.arange(20000000),
         'VAL' : np.random.randn(20000000)})
```

### case #1 : fixe format

```
df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',append=False,format ='fixed')
```

now , i read ten ten time the df, i work without high memory consumption

```
for a in range(10):
    df1 = pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df')
```

### case #2 : table format

```
df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',append=False,format ='table')
```

now , i read ten ten time the df, it doesnt release memory on each itération.memory consuption is getting to high

```
for a in range(10):
    df1 = pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df')
```

Any suggestion ?

windows 64bits python 3.4, pandas 0.15.1

Comment: you need to gc.collect(). The table creation creates more objects which then need to be collected. They WILL be collected eventually, but you may need to force it sooner if you are really doing those kind of loops (which in general is not a great idea, that's the point of the selection syntax).

Comment: the loop is just here to point the increase of memory consuption.

Answer (score 1):

Using a smaller file n=1MM.

Their table format allocates about 2x memory then collects it. This is mainly of function of the storage format.

```
In [12]: %mprun -f f f()
Filename: test.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     5    115.1 MiB      0.0 MiB   def f():
     6    125.8 MiB     10.7 MiB       pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df')
     7    125.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       gc.collect()
('',)

In [13]: %mprun -f f2 f2()
Filename: test.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     9    125.8 MiB      0.0 MiB   def f2():
    10    228.5 MiB    102.7 MiB       pd.read_hdf('test2.h5','df')
    11    115.0 MiB   -113.5 MiB       gc.collect()
```